# Is there a rule-based implementation of weighted abduction other than the PTTP?

Tags: lo.logic

Is there an implementation of weighted abduction other than the PT theorem prover? A Google search reveals the PTTP and a few statistical approaches but I'm interested in a rule-based approach. The PTTP is too slow with large knowledge bases. Since I couldn't google up anything useful I guess there's none (maybe statistics is the way to go as abduction is intractable) but maybe someone knows of an alternative in a different branch of logic programming (such as ASP).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of any alternatives but some first-order abductive problems can be recast as evaluation of stable models.